# Run external program with VBA

Tags: api, excel, vba

I am trying to write Excel VBA code to open an external windows program and then open a file within that external program. I've figured out how to open the program using the "Shell" command but I don't know how to use any of the programs functions once its opened. This is what I have so far.
Thanks!

```
Program = "C:\Program Files\EP-Quick\EP-Quick.exe"
TaskID = Shell(Program, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First review SendKeys in VBA help and:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278655(v=office.14).aspx

Then, using Google, try to find examples specific to your application